# Sharing regional variables when using recursive functions in Python

Tags: python, list, recursion, local-variables

I'm studying algorithms with Python.
While working on the recursive function, we try to pop the 0th part of the array whenever the for statement proceeds in the following situation.
However, [arrangement] is shared within the recursive called part, so it doesn't work out as I thought.

The regional variable is used within the recursive function, but the regional variable continues to be shared in each recursive function, resulting in incorrect results.

In the code below, each recursive call should not involve each other in regional variables.
Tell me how to do it.

```
def jong(case, a, b, sumX, sumY, n, min):
    n = int(n)
    if len(case) == n:
        print(case)
        result = (a-2*sumX)*(a-2*sumX) + (b-2*sumY)*(b-2*sumY)
        if min == -1:
            min = result
            return min
        if min > result:
            min = result
        return min
    for i in range(0, len(case)):
        sumX = sumX + int(case[0][0])
        sumY = sumY + int(case[0][1])
        popArr = case.copy()
        popArr.pop(0)
        min = jong(popArr, a, b, sumX, sumY, n, min)
        sumX = sumX - int(case[0][0])
        sumY = sumY - int(case[0][1])
        case.pop(0)
    return min
```

In the above code, I should not let each recursive function share the "case.pop(0)" part.

Comment: `case` will not be shared.  You are passing a copy of `case`, in `popArr`.  It's not a deep copy, so the objects inside will not be duplicated, but it's not clear whether you expect that.

Comment: The question is a bit hard to answer because we don't know which variables you're talking about (there are **a lot** of variables in your function); nor do we know what algorithm you're trying to implement.

Comment: PS: You might have noticed that name `min` is highlighted in a different colour than other variables. That's because `min` is the name of a builtin function in python. Reusing the name of a builtin function is usually discouraged, for two reasons. (1) People who read your code might be a bit confused, since they will expect `min` to be the builtin function rather than a new variable. (2) Occasionally there might be unexpected consequences; by reusing the name `min`, you're shadowing the builtin, and if you then call a function that uses builtin `min` internally, things are going to break.

Comment: What's this code supposed to do?

Comment: [link](https://www.acmicpc.net/problem/1007)
The URL above is the algorithm The way my algorithm works is

If it's [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
`[1 2 3]
[1 2 4]
[1 2 5]
[1 2 6]
[1 3 4]
[1 3 5]
[1 3 6]
[1 4 5]
[1 4 6]
[1 5 6]
[2 3 4]`
We are going to implement an algorithm that proceeds in this way.
When the first 1 is finished, I try to pop 1 because I don't need it afterwards.

The problem arises here, but if you recognize it as the same name Array in the recursive function and exit the recursive function and proceed with the next for statement, the length of the case is already zero